# Surprise "S" network community structure measure

Tags: graph, social-networking, cluster-analysis

Does anybody know if there already exists an implementation of this evaluation measure in R, or some other language?

This is the wikipedia page of the evaluation measure:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surprise_%28networks%29

Comment: That would be very interesting to know. A naive implementation of the formula containing binomial coefficients is feasible only for small networks, since integers and doubles will quickly overflow.

Comment: The Wikipedia entry is annotated with this caveat: *A major contributor to this article appears to have a close connection with its subject*. It seems indeed highly biased. For example, "Besides its empirical superior performance, S has obvious theoretical advantages over Q and Q-based indexes". It has all the looks of a self-promoting wiki page. To put this in context, there are lies, damned lies, then there is statistics, and *then* there is cluster analysis / community detection. It is a very fuzzy subject, and claims such as the above just do not make sense.

Answer (score 2):

Found this on github. there's also implementations in matlab and c++.
cheers!
https://github.com/raldecoa/compute-Surprise/blob/master/r_code/computeSurprise.R